# How to find the process which has a lock on a file in a linux environment

Tags: linux, git, github, kill

So I have a problem similar to this individual...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635429/git-rename-from-index-lock-to-index-failed

So it seems that he eventually solves his problem by finding a process which has a lock on his .git/index file. He however does not explain how he found out that this process has a lock on his .git/index file. So if someone can explain to me how he figured that out that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two commands that will list open files, [`fuser`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) and [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof).

Answer (score 0):

Use the utility `lsof`.  If will tell the process that has a lock on a file.